# how to set server path in vs code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

How to set local server set path in vs code. Now I am getting like this http://localhost:8080/ but i want http://localhost/myproject/index.html it is look like sometimes http://localhost/myproject/). Now it is opening in Chrome but I want to set Firefox.

package.json

```
{
 "name": "TS",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "demo project.",
 "scripts": {
 "lite": "lite-server --port 8080",
 "start": "npm run lite"
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "devDependencies": {
 "lite-server": "^1.3.1"
 } 
 }
```

tasks.json

```
   {
   // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
   // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "tasks": [
    {
        "type": "npm",
        "script": "lite",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "npm",
        "script": "start",
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

VSC will open your default Browser. Simply set Firefox a default one